# Error in creating a matrix in R from comma separated dataset

Tags: r, matrix

Sorry!!!

I don't know how to frame a question succinctly but I will try to explain what is my problem and where the problem occurs in steps in my R-script.

I've a dataset called "CBF_TRAIN".

Step 1: Am trying to read them in the form of table using the following.

```
>dtrain <- read.table("CBF/CBF_TRAIN", as.is = T)

>View(dtrain)

The resulting output "dtrain" looks like this..

1,-0.46428,-0.55505,-0.84284,-0.8659,-0.9364,........

1,-0.89697,-0.68569,-1.3514,-1.4587,-1.1653,.........

1,-0.4647,-0.56774,-0.032023,-0.63505,-0.60283,......

3,-0.18719,-0.62081,-0.81566,-0.5214,-0.79042,.......

2,-1.136,-1.3192,-1.8446,-0.78869,-0.25172,..........  

...

...
```

Step 2: Label the dataset i.e. assign first elements of the vector array in every row as shown below

```
> labels_train = unlist(dtrain[,1])

> str(labels_train)
```

The resulting output "labels_dtrain" looks like this...

```
chr [1:30] "1,-0.46428,-0.55505,-0.84284,-0.8659,-0.9364,-0.81727,-0.26361,-1.258,-1.2504,-0.91831,-0.9221,-0.98449,-1.2881,-1.1435,-1.0489"| __truncated__ ...
```

Step 3: Create a matrix using the following command.

```
> data_train = matrix(unlist(dtrain[,-1]), nrow = length(labels_train))

This throws an Output with ERROR as shown below. 

Error in matrix(unlist(dtrain[, -1]), nrow = length(labels_train)) :  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

I'm a beginner in R-programming, trying to debug open-source program and learn through reverse engineering. Appreciate your needful help in trying to understand and fix this error.

ThnX,

KMB

Comment: Are you looking for either read.csv, or sep="," inside read.table?

Comment: probably you want `read.table("CBF/CBF_TRAIN", as.is = TRUE, sep = ',')` instead

Comment: Right after the input to dtrain, assuming you fixed the missing sep="," argument,  all you needed was: `mtrain <- data.matrix(dtrain)`

Comment: I think the problem lies in "step 3". Could you pls. suggest how to fix that line?